# running python and mysql with docker error - cannot connect

Tags: python, docker, mysql-connector

I am using mysql-connector, when ever I run the container using docker I get this error:

```
mysql.connector.errors.InterfaceError: 2003: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'db:3306' (-5 No address associated with hostname)
```

but when I run the project using python only it executes with no errors

I want to use phpmyadmin only for the database please help.

Comment: Where is the database located?  Is it within the docker container?  Have you created the database in a separate docker container?  I tend to prefer to create a docker container for each component separately and then open ports to permit communication between them.  Note that if you build a separate docker for your database, you will want to mount a separate storage folder within the docker to keep the data persistent.  If this interests you, I can paste some sample code that you can work with.

Comment: Sounds good, yes please I want it really urgent too

Comment: And btw the database is located within the main.py and the docker container

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create a docker from your linux machine:

```
docker pull mysql:latest
```

To run it and mount a persistent folder with port access on 3306 (std port for mysql):

```
docker run --name=mysql_dockerdb --env="MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=<your_password>" -p 3306:3306 -v /home/ubuntu/sql_db/<your_dbasename>:/var/lib/mysql -d mysql:latest
```

To connect to the docker instance so that you can create the database within the docker:

```
docker exec -it mysql_dockerdb mysql -uroot -p<your_password>
```

My SQL code to establish the database:

```
CREATE DATABASE dockerdb;
CREATE USER 'newuser'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'newpassword';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON dockerdb.* to 'newuser'@'%';
ALTER USER 'username'@'%' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'userpassword';
```

You will now have a docker running with a persistent SQL database.  You connect to it from your Python code.  I am running Flask mySql.  You will want to keep your passwords in environment variables.  I am using a Mac so therefore my ~/.bash_profile contains:

```
export RDS_LOGIN="mysql+pymysql://<username>:<userpassword>@<dockerhost_ip>/dockerdb"
```

Within Python:

```
import os

SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = os.environ.get('RDS_LOGIN')
```

And at that point you should be able to connect in your usual Python manner.  Note that I've glossed over any security aspects on the presumption this is local behind a firewall.