# How to access an .xls (or .csv) in the cloud, via my flask application?

Tags: python, flask, heroku

I have deployed my first flask application, using heroku.

Although it is not very elegant, I just wanted to get something finished and deployed.

I have a data set, that I update using a locally run python script, which exports an .xls file. This .xls file is then the data I send to my heroku app, which delivers the data for my website.

Instead of having to commit and push this file to my heroku git, everytime I change it, I was wondering if it was possible just to save my .xls where it is accessible somewhere on the internet, and then my flask app could just send an API or something to retrieve this data.

Apologies, this is my first time working with flask, so my question may not be worded correctly.

Does anyone have any insights, of information on how to better operate this?

Comment: Why not keep it with your git?  What's the advantage to keeping it separate?

Comment: Is there a way to automatically push this file to my git whenever I update it? I am using a python script to generate this file, so if I could code that into that script, that would work. Sorry I'm a noob here, trying to learn

Comment: I'm guessing that you're not using an editor such as PyCharm?  PyCharm will manage git repositories, and so long as you store the file within the directory scope of your project, it will automatically update it when you push to your git.  PyCharm Community is free to use.

Comment: I am using PyCharm actually, I guess what I need to do is to set up so that it automatically pushes any file names to my git.

Comment: Any idea how to do this? I'm looking at using subprocess in python to run the necessary command lines to push to my git, and then to my heroku app

Comment: There is gitpython, i've never used it but it might be something you can use. Have a look at the tutorial here https://gitpython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

Comment: Im still trying to grasp the data flows.  If you are trying to store data, you might have more success with a pysql database.  Where are you hosting your site?  If you can run a docker at your site, I could pass you some code to setup a sql database for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to share some locally produced data with your remote website (and potentially share data to end users there), I'd recommend to create a dockerized MySQL database that both your local application and your remote server can utilize.  I have drafted instructions to do this in my reply in the thread below:

[running python and mysql with docker error - cannot connect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65460405/running-python-and-mysql-with-docker-error-cannot-connect/65465270#65465270)

I can appreciate that you're still learning (and keep going!).  If you need additional help to write the connection code to the docker, let me know and I can drop some more help in the comments!